# Formatting Bar Graph Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a simple 2 dimensional Bar Graph for two lists in python.
(note that max of this list is 4)
I want to plot this list and its corresponding index using Matplotlib.
My code is this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
bitpos = np.arange(len(sumlist))
pl.bar(bitpos,sumlist, align='center', alpha=0.5)
pl.ylabel('mismatch count')
pl.xlabel('bitposition')
```

The graph although plots correctly but the bars are touching the top of the graph (see the graph below) I want to create some empty space above the graph for a better presentation.

[Example Plot to illustrate my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgbmg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some space to the top of your plot, you can add something like:

```
pl.ylim((0., 5.))
```

to the bottom of your current script.This changes the y limits of your plot to 0 and 5 (currently they are 0 and 4).